# Does the Lucky feat allow the character to see the enemy's die roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

If an enemy B attack a character A, where A has the Lucky feat, and A wants to spend a Luck point, *in which moment can character A can spend that Luck point*?

Can Character A see/know the natural result of Enemy B's roll before deciding whether or not to use a Luck Point?

If no, Can Character A see/know the natural result of Enemy B's roll *after* deciding to use the Luck Point,but *before* choosing which die?

Comment: This actually seems like two different but related questions: "Can I see the DM's roll before making a decision?" and "Can I know the result of the roll before deciding whether to use a luck point"

Comment: @Rubiksmoose The first question element that you note already has answers on this SE.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose [this one is related but not the one I am recalling](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84660/22566)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast [related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102063/what-rolls-should-players-get-to-see)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## It does not specifically state, but the feat becomes much less interesting/powerful if you don't know the raw result.

The text for lucky states, emphasis mine (PHB, 167):

> You can also spend one luck point when an attack roll is made against you. Roll a d20, and then **choose whether the attack uses the attacker’s roll or yours**.

If you don't have knowledge of the initial d20, that heavily implies that you must know what the raw roll was in order to compare it against yours. If you didn't have the opportunity to know, then it would work more like the Portent Ability of a Divination Wizard but that you roll your D20 at the time of the event. In order to decide which die result to use, you have to know what the numbers are.

See [this related answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55362/23024) for some more discussion already covered on this.

### No modifiers known, no outcome known

Knowing the raw result of the dice is not the same thing as knowing the outcome and the rules for Lucky specifically state that you *don't* know the outcome. The player still must choose between the number rolled on the DMs die vs the number rolled on your lucky die.

### Open rolls vs Behind the screen

This is where it gets tricky, as not every DM rolls openly. If you (or your DM) chooses not to disclose any rolls, that significantly impacts the value of the lucky feat - and this should be discussed *before* someone chooses the feat. The rules are not explicit, but implicit in the ability for the player to know the number on the die.

And yes, it is still a choice when picking a known quantity (your roll) vs what is behind door number 3 (DMs roll), but that is significantly less impactful, interesting, and fun. It also means the player must be Lucky in their own roll *as well as* lucky in guessing what the DM rolled. If a DM chooses to keep those rolls hidden, I personally would not recommend picking this feat.

### Crawford implies knowing natural result

In [this twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/756178023561383937), Jeremy Crawford suggests the import and intent of knowing the natural result:

> If a player character ability relies on knowing a monster's roll, a DM may say what the roll is or show it

### When to know

The feat does not state *when* you know the roll. The implication would be knowing the roll so you can decide if you want to use the Feat, but a compromise with a DM who prefers to keep things hidden could be to show after you've chosen to use the Feat. However, I think Crawford's Tweet above implies that you should know before so as to decide whether or not the resource expenditure is worth it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73529/discussion-between-nautarch-and-david-coffron).

Comment: Per the description of the feat, it sounds like you would choose to use the luck point before you know the enemy creature's roll. You would only find out their roll after that so that you can choose between their roll and yours.

Comment: @V2Blast I could definitely see a reading like that. My only hesitation is that means it's basically another version of Inspiration that you can also use against someone. I'd think Lucky has a slightly different mechanic where you see that first roll, say "Oh hells, no...I'm feeling lucky!" and roll the 2nd d20.